# Problem to get file properties (sharepointClient)

Tags: document, file, client

I'am trying to get the size of a file of a sharepoint account but I have no access to the data. [image]

How Can I get this properties ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

follow the below code. You need to load the file property you want to access. This code get all files, you can modify it to suit your needs

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    var results = clientContext.Web.Lists
        .GetById(listId).RootFolder.Files;

    clientContext.Load(results, files => files
            .Include(file => file.Length));

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var file in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
    }
}
```